# Expect that a JSON has just a particular set of keys in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am testing a JSON API, and right now I do this:

```
expect(json).to have_key('name')
expect(json).to have_key('age')
```

How can I make sure that the JSON has **just** the keys `name` and `age`, and no other keys?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [`#contain_exactly`](http://rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-expectations/RSpec/Matchers#contain_exactly-instance_method) matcher:

```
expect(json.keys).to contain_exactly('name', 'age')
```

### Examples

#### Number #1

Spec:

```
describe "Hash" do
  subject { {a: 2, b: 3} }

  it "passes" do
    expect(subject.keys).to contain_exactly(:a, :b)
  end
end
```

Let's run it :

```
arup@linux-wzza:~/Ruby> rspec spec/test_spec.rb
.

Finished in 0.00227 seconds (files took 0.13131 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

#### Number #2

Spec:

```
describe "Hash" do
  subject { {a: 2, b: 3} }

  it "fails" do
    expect(subject.keys).to contain_exactly(:a)
  end
end
```

Let's run it:

```
arup@linux-wzza:~/Ruby> rspec spec/test_spec.rb
F

Failures:

  1) Hash fails
     Failure/Error: expect(subject.keys).to contain_exactly(:a)
       expected collection contained:  [:a]
       actual collection contained:    [:a, :b]
       the extra elements were:        [:b]
     # ./spec/test_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00243 seconds (files took 0.13206 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/test_spec.rb:6 # Hash fails
```

#### Number #3

Spec:

```
describe "Hash" do
  subject { {a: 2, b: 3, c: 4} }

  it "fails" do
    expect(subject.keys).to contain_exactly(:a, :b)
  end
end
```

Let's run it:

```
arup@linux-wzza:~/Ruby> rspec spec/test_spec.rb
F

Failures:

  1) Hash fails
     Failure/Error: expect(subject.keys).to contain_exactly(:a, :b)
       expected collection contained:  [:a, :b]
       actual collection contained:    [:a, :b, :c]
       the extra elements were:        [:c]
     # ./spec/test_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00243 seconds (files took 0.13301 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/test_spec.rb:6 # Hash fails
arup@linux-wzza:~/Ruby>
```

#### Number #4

When dealing with JSON keys, the splat operator (`*`) comes in handy to manage a list of arguments.

Spec:

```
describe "Hash" do
  subject { {a: 2, b: 3} }
  let(:json_keys) { %w{a b} }

  it "passes" do
    expect(subject.keys).to contain_exactly(*json_keys)
  end
end
```

Let's run it :

```
arup@linux-wzza:~/Ruby> rspec spec/test_spec.rb
.

Finished in 0.00227 seconds (files took 0.13131 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

Comment: Or that nice answer did not know about `#contain_exactly` although it seems syntax should be `contain_exactly('name','age')`

Comment: What's great about this approach is how it alerts you about even tiny changes to the API you're consuming.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
expect(json.keys.sort).to eq(["age","name"])
```

Or

```
expect(json.keys).to match_array(["name","age"])
```

I am assuming the `json` object is pre-parsed such as `let(:json){JSON.parse(something)}`. If so this is now a `Hash` and `#keys` will return an `Array` of the `keys` so compare that to the expected `Array`.

If not pre-parsed then

```
expect(JSON.parse(json).keys).to match_array(["name","age"])
```

Comment: @ArupRakshit not according to [RSpec](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/contain-exactly-matcher). This states it is basically an alias for `#contain_exactly`. I can't say I have tested it though...

Comment: Yes..You are right. I misread it. :-) They are same having some *syntactical* diff.